# New to CodeBlocks, how do I create a new file?

Tags: codeblocks

I am starting to learn C and I have decieded to use CodeBlocks to compile my programs.

I ran into some trouble. I created a new project console application and automaticly there was a "hello world" program. I want to make a program of my own in this project so I created a new file, but when I run the new file is automaticly runs the hello world? I have built and run.

[image]

Comment: You should only have one `main`. Did you remove the old one? A simpler way would perhaps be to *replace* the code in the generated file instead of adding a new one.

Comment: Ohh darn, It has been sometime since I programmed last. I mixed this up with workspace. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeblocks does not automatically check if the application is out-of-date before running.  You must compile first, then run.

Since it appears that both main.c and test.c have a 'main' function defined, that should generate an error.  Remove the main.c file from your project, and the new main function should be called.